# Alternative to Ethersweep

Tags: web3js

Im experimenting with the erc20 token. When trying to write contract on etherscan the Web3 connection just don't work, and I don't know why. But then I thought that perhaps Ethersweep could do something similar and hopefully good also, but no, that site is promising something Awesome! That is a good thing of course but is there any similar service or site that offers some sort or Erc20 swapping also?

Answer (score 1):

Ethersweep is not meant for testing smart contracts. It's for converting supported tokens on one wallet to ETH in another wallet. It will also move existing ETH balance to the destination wallet.

Nobody can tell why writing the contract on Etherscan failed without knowing the contents of the contract.

To swap ERC20 token to ETH, you need to first finish the contract code and then list it on exchange that accepts ERC20 tokens. Some exchanges require that the token is maintained by incorporated company, so individual persons can't request listing ERC20 tokens.